# My Quicksort fails when sorting pre-sorted items, how to improve?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, implementation

This is a standard recursive quickSort implementation, and it succeeds at sorting larger lists for unsorted items but not for "pre-sorted" items. I knew it would take longer, but not fail altogether. Any possible improvements?

```
void quickSort(int *array, size_t count) {
    int pivot = array[count - 1];
    int max_index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i) 
    {
        if (array[i] < pivot) {
            swap(array[i], array[max_index]);
            ++max_index;
        }
    }
    swap(array[max_index], array[count - 1]);

    if (max_index > 1)
        quickSort(array, max_index);
    if (count - max_index - 1 > 1)
        quickSort(array + max_index + 1, count - max_index - 1);
}
```

Comment: What does "fails" mean?

Comment: Can you show an example of input that fails, along with the output?

Comment: Now executing your Quick Sort of 9999 items.
Your Quick Sort took 0.005833 Seconds.
Now Executing your Quick Sort of 9999 pre-sorted items.

(process 16128) exited with code -1073741571.

^^^^That's the output I receive, and it's a tester program for when I put in 9,999 items to sort. It doesn't output the time indicating something went wrong altogether, maybe stack overflow.

Comment: Which `swap` function are you using?

Comment: Using the <algorithm> library std::swap

Comment: @sabowsky try using `int count` instead of `size_t count`

Comment: @sabowsky Tester programs can be useful for finding errors, but they might not be the best tool for debugging. A good next step for you would be to create your own test program where you give your function a pre-sorted array of, let's say, three elements and you step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @JaMiT The issue is that it works fine on 100 items, so I'm thinking it might have to do with the style of recursion and stack overflow

Comment: @VladimirNikitin not an option, but thank you haha.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the choice of a pivot value. You're using the rightmost value (`array[count-1]`) which can lead to [worst-case behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis) for an already sorted sequence. You create a partition with size 1 and another partition with size n-1. This causes a chain of n-1 recursive calls, leading to poor performance 
 O(N<sup>2</sup>) or a stack overflow.

You should consider alternatives like:

- A random index
- The middle index
- The median of three indexes (first, middle, last)
- Something more complicated like a median of medians ([ninther](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/06/23/tukey-median-ninther/))